# Li tag is not aligning correctly in Chrome. How to fix it?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to create a menu and style it. I have also used some css animations to show a description (span) when hovered. This menu is working properly under Firefox. But in Chrome, there's a white space above the menu. When I check the li tag through Firebug, its show me that the li element is not aligned properly. Its moved upward. Its not happening on firefox. (please check the screenshots below). How can I fix this?

**Update** : I have just uploaded the site to Heroku : http://aqueous-wildwood-4051.herokuapp.com/. You will see the issue in this live site.

**In chrome :**
[image]

**In Firefox** :
[image]

**Here's the code of my sidebar :**

```
    <aside id="sidebar" role="complementary">
      <nav id="side-nav" role="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li  ><a href="/"><div id='side-nav-home' class='listitem'><span class='listtitle'>Home</span><span class='description'>Home page of SLNYAA</span></div></a></li>
          <li  ><a href="/about"><div id='side-nav-about' class='listitem'><span class='listtitle'>About Us</span><span class='description'>Learn more about us</span></div></a></li>
          <li  ><a href="#"><div id='side-nav-handbook' class='listitem'><span class='listtitle'>Handbook</span><span class='description'>Read our handbook</span></div></a></li>
          <li  ><a href="#"><div id='side-nav-join' class='listitem'><span class='listtitle'>Join Us</span><span class='description'>Join our program</span></div></a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </aside>
```

**Here is the CSS :**

```
    #sidebar {
        border-left: 1px solid #EDEDED;
        box-shadow: -3px 0 9px rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.2);
        float: right;
        min-height: 365px;
        width: 24%;

        #side-nav{


            ul {
                margin-top: 0px !important;
                height: 187px;
                list-style: none outside none;
                margin-left: 0;
                padding-left: 0;
                width: 100%;

                li{
                    height: 46px;

                    a{
                        text-decoration: none;
                        font-size: 14px;
                        color: #fff;
                        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #757575;
                        border-right: 1px solid rgba(217, 217, 217, 0);
                        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
                        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
                        -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
                        -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
                        transition: all 0.3s ease-in;


                        .listitem {
                            list-style: none outside none;
                            height: 32px;
                            text-align: center;
                            padding-top: 10px;
                            -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
                            -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
                            -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
                            -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
                            transition: all 0.3s ease-in;



                            .description {
                                visibility: hidden;
                                position: absolute;
                                font-size: 12px;
                                color: #FFFFFF;
                                font-weight: bold;
                                position: absolute;
                                margin-left: 8px;
                                margin-top: 4px;
                                opacity: 0;
                                -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in;
                                -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in;
                                -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in;
                                -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-in;
                                transition: all 0.6s ease-in;
                            }



                            &:hover {
                                text-align: left;


                                .description {
                                    visibility: visible;
                                    opacity: 1;
                                }

                                .listtitle{
                                    margin-left: 7px;
                                    border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
                                    padding-right: 7px;   
                                }
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }

                #side-nav-home{
                    background-color: #ED0042;
                    border: 2px solid #E87998;
                }

                #side-nav-about{
                    background-color: #e1cf3b;
                    border: 2px solid #C4BD80;
                }

                #side-nav-handbook{
                    background-color: #009dda;
                    border: 2px solid #5EADCC;
                }

                #side-nav-join{
                    background-color: #6ba01e;
                    border: 2px solid #98AB7D;
                }


            }
        }     
    }
```

Comment: I think you should give your nav an absolute pos and ul relative, then set ul top to 0 in order to stick at top of nav.

Comment: @raminomrani Not working my friend :) The ul is already sicked to the top of the nav. The li also have sicked to the top of the ul. But the a and the div inside is not.

Comment: can you share a jsFiddle?

Comment: @raminomrani I have never used it! But after adding the css and the html it didn't work.

Comment: @raminomrani I have just uploaded the site to Heroku. Please check it : http://aqueous-wildwood-4051.herokuapp.com/ I think it will be better than JSFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: block` to the `a` CSS style

```
#main-container-border #main-container #sidebar #side-nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #757575;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(217, 217, 217, 0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S3eGu/)

Comment: I met the same issue, another choice is to make LI as `display:table` and A as `display:table-cell`.